# Time taken for inserting a row in a table with autoincrementing primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

We have learnt that ordered file system is not good for insertion as complexity is proportional to number of records (Worst Case is sthe Primary key (ID) is inserted in descending order).

But if we have an autoincrementing primary key, then, it always be added at the end - thus taking care of the bad complexity of insertion.

My question is - does it work this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. You're always going to have index re-orgs, but as long as they don't happen to the Clustered index they aren't a problem. So for your clustered Primary Key autoincrement is the way to go usually.

Comment: Its a table where im not deleting any rows at all... So, it must be good

Comment: It is. And deleting won't be too much of a problem either.